# Send data continuously from flask api to javascript frontend

Tags: javascript, flask

I want to make a website which visualize in real time some simulations which take some time to compute and I would like to know the easiest way to do it.

For now, the JavaScript front-end get the final result in once from the flask API and show it to the user. I would like the backend to send the result of the simulation in real-time, with batch of data at time intervals while it still computes, and the frontend to display the results in real time without having to re-load the page each time. How could I do that easily?

Answer (score 2):

There are two common methods for doing this:

1. Web Sockets
2. Server-Sent Events (SSE)

**If the frontend of your application needs to speak to the backend very often**, then it would be best to open up a [web socket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) for this channel of communication. Here is a list of popular frameworks for commonly used languages, including Python: https://github.com/facundofarias/awesome-websockets

**If the frontend of your application just needs to listen for updates**, then it may be better to use [open up an event stream with SSE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events). Note that this can be done nowadays in most browsers in plain JavaScript at the frontend, but the backend may be a little more involved. Since you're using Flask, you might want to take a look at [Flask-SSE](https://flask-sse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html).